# Why are some users able to add special characters to their user name, but I can't enter a Malayalam one?

Tags: support, display-names

I saw that someone added a special character to their screen name.
An example: 웃

When I copied that in my profile name and clicked on save, it worked.

But when I try with something like `സാഗർ വി` (*SAGAR V* in Malayalam), it shows the following error:

[image]

The message clearly says that **Display Name can only contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes or hyphens and must start with a letter or digit**.

But then how such characters are added?

Comment: Is the whole point of the exercise to avoid people directly replying to you? I think it is easy enough to just ignore notifications...

Comment: simply no. As mentioned in the question, I would like to change my display name to Sagar V സാഗർ വി @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: See [What characters are allowed for the display name?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/106339) and [Using Japanese letters in the username](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/204589) on Meta.SE

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Stack Overflow has a feature where when typing the @ symbol, if any users that are pingable have names that start with characters which don't exist on english keyboards, they are automatically populated in the pop-up list of pingable users.

Comment: @tiny unless you happen to use mobile version of the site... I was more interested if I guessed reason why OP wanted they name to be non-recognizable by most visitors. So now I know my guess was wrong.

Comment: is it off topic, I doubt because of the downvotes

Comment: @Pekka웃 See, you (your username) is being discussed here. :)

Comment: First I write his full name, But before posting , I had a rethink and I removed the name from the post because it may be a personnel harassment.

Comment: @PeterDuniho He edited the post once. you can see it in the rev's

Comment: Ah, so he did. I guess he'll see the comment after all. :)

Answer (score 50):

You are free to use any character that is a member of the [.NET `\w` character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#CharacterClassSyntax).

This includes any Unicode letter categories (Ll, Lu, Lt, Lo, Lm), connecting characters (Pc, connecting punctuation, underscores really) and numbers (Nd), with a dash of hyphen, space and apostrophe thrown in.

Your example, `സാഗർ വി` doesn't fit those rules:

```
U+0D38  സ       [Lo] MALAYALAM LETTER SA
U+0D3E  ാ       [Mc] MALAYALAM VOWEL SIGN AA
U+0D17  ഗ       [Lo] MALAYALAM LETTER GA
U+0D7C  ർ       [Lo] MALAYALAM LETTER CHILLU RR
U+0020          [Zs] SPACE
U+0D35  വ       [Lo] MALAYALAM LETTER VA
U+0D3F  ി       [Mc] MALAYALAM VOWEL SIGN I
```

Note the `[Mc]` (Mark, spacing combining) characters; they are not part of the letter, number or punctuation groups, and are the reason the name is rejected.

There **may** be a case for including the Mc category in the permitted character list, as it primarily [consists of combining characters from several specialised scripts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mc/list.htm). That'd have to be a new feature request.

Comment: Yes we can ;-) ...

Comment: And for anyone else curious about why `웃` is then allowed it turns out this is a [Hangul Syllable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Syllables)

Comment: That's some great in-depth explanation. And *this* is why I sigh when people say they "added Unicode support" by making sure multibyte characters aren't chopped up by mistake, as though Unicode was just "like ASCII, but wider" :P